# How to obtain: $\lim_{x \to -\infty}\big(\sqrt{x^2+3x+2}+x-1\big)$?

Tags: calculus, limits, education

Please help me to do my homework
Take look to the below image I would like a solution step by step of
$$
\lim_{x \to -\infty}\left(\sqrt{x^2+3x+2}+x-1\right).
$$
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2I3qS.jpg)

Comment: See the method : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1766582/evaluate-the-lim-x-to-infty-x-sqrtx2-2x/1766586#1766586

Comment: "Please help me to do my homework" - well, at least you are honest about it. But it's not recommended to use Math.SE as a homework help site, especially without any effort of your own shown.

Comment: @YuriyS Yes I did effort, but when I try to draw a curve I find it illogical. I know where  I do the error but I do not have enough skills.
When I put the limit in [link](wolframalpha.com) I got a result -5/2 . but  I do not understand how to count it because I forgot when you drop some variable out of the root, you must add the absolute value. That's it and sorry if I did some linguistic errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. One may write, as $x \to -\infty$,
$$
\begin{align}
\sqrt{x^2+3x+2}+x-1&=\frac{(x^2+3x+2)-(x-1)^2}{\sqrt{x^2+3x+2}-(x-1)}
\\\\&=\frac{5+1/x}{-\sqrt{1+3/x+2/x^2}-1+1/x}
\end{align}
$$ where we have used $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|=-x$ since $x<0$.

Comment: Thanl you so much
but I don't understand why you write −x since x<0.

Comment: @Mourad Kaaroudi You are welcome. Do you get this: $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|=-x$ for $x<0$? Recall that for example the absolute value of $-7$ is $|-7|=-(-7)=7$ since $-7<0$.

Comment: Yes yes I understand now thank you

Answer (score 1):

Similarly completing the square of $x^2+3x+2=(x+\frac{3}{2})^2-\frac{1}{4}$ as we go to $-\infty$ we get that the square root of this is equivalent to $-x-\frac{3}{2}$ because the $-\frac{1}{4}$ isn't going to matter as we go to $-\infty$ now our limit is $\lim_{x\to-\infty} -x-\frac{3}{2}+x-1$ which is then just $-\frac{5}{2}$