# Why is $\lim\limits_{x\to -\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+2x}-x}$ equal to $0$?

Tags: limits, infinity

So I made one exercise, which was $\lim_{x\to +\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-2x}-x}$ I solved this one by:

$\lim \limits_{x\to +\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-2x}-x} \frac{\sqrt{x^2-2x}+x}{\sqrt{x^2-2x}+x} $

$\lim \limits_{x\to +\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{1-\frac{2}{x}}+x}{-2x}$

$\lim \limits_{x\to +\infty} \frac{\sqrt{1-\frac{2}{x}}+1}{-2} = -1 $

The next exercise is $\lim \limits_{x\to -\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+2x}-x}$
I thought that I could solve this one in the same way by:

$\lim \limits_{x\to -\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+2x}-x} \frac{\sqrt{x^2+2x}+x}{\sqrt{x^2+2x}+x} $

$\lim \limits_{x\to -\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{x}}+x}{2x}$

$\lim \limits_{x\to -\infty} \frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{x}}+1}{2} = 1 $

But apparently, the answer is $0$...

Why can't the second one be solved in the same way as the first?
And why is the answer $0$?

Comment: the answer is $1$

Comment: Can you show how apparently you are getting 0? because answer is ${1}$

Comment: Your answer is correct

Comment: according to WolframAlpha and the answer sheet it isn't...

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+x+to+infinity+1%2F(root(x%5E2%2B2x)-x)

Comment: Are you sure you have not read the function off wrongly in that case? http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Limit%5B1%2F(Sqrt%5Bx%5E2%2B2x%5D-x),x-%3Einfinity%5D

Comment: sorry missed a negative sign in the limit.

Comment: @John Bentin Can you please say me why this limit equals -1? His  answer is not correct.

Comment: If $x \to -\infty$ the answer is 0.

Comment: Because eventually $x$ is negative $\sqrt{x^2}=-x$ and not $x$.

Comment: Is it $x\to+\infty$ or $x\to -\infty$? You have written something odd.

Comment: The first one is positive infinity the second one is negative infinity. @s.harp I don't get it. Could you explain your argument?

Comment: $\lim \limits_{x\to -\infty}\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2}}{x}$ is $-1$, not $+1$.

Comment: @zakaria square root of $x^2$ is $|x|$

Comment: @BehrouzMaleki: The OP's answer was correct for the question originally posted. But changing the limit from $\infty$ to $-\infty$ (wrongly typeset) obviously changes the answer.

Comment: @John Bentin $$\lim_{x\to -\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+2x}-x}=0$$ and $$\lim_{x\to +\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+2x}-x}=1$$ Indeed this limit doesn't equal $-1$.

Comment: @BehrouzMaleki: Yes. We have no disagreement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When $x\rightarrow-\infty$, you don't have $0$ as denominator, but $+\infty$, because when $x \rightarrow-\infty, \sqrt{x^2 -2x} \sim |x|$ and, as $x < 0$, $|x| = -x$, so you have $\lim\limits_{x\to -\infty}\frac {1}{-x-x} = \lim\limits_{x\to -\infty}\frac {1}{-2x} = 0$.

Answer (score 3):

We already have answers showing correct ways to solve the problem.
What I found interesting was the implied question:
where is the error in the steps taken in the body of the question,
which appeared to show that the limit is $1$?

The steps in question are
\begin{align}
\newcommand{\?}{\stackrel{?}{=}}
\lim_{x\to -\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+2x}-x} 
  &\? \lim_{x\to -\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+2x}-x}
                          \frac{\sqrt{x^2+2x}+x}{\sqrt{x^2+2x}+x} \tag1\\
  &\? \lim_{x\to -\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{x}}+x}{2x} \tag2\\
  &\? \lim_{x\to -\infty} \frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{x}}+1}{2} \tag3\\
  &\? 1 \tag4
\end{align}

The error is in the third step (from line $2$ to line $3$).
In fact, if $x < 0,$ then $\sqrt{x^2} = -x,$ so
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to -\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{x}}+x}{2x} 
 &= \lim_{x\to -\infty} \frac{-x\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{x}}+x}{2x} \\
  &= \lim_{x\to -\infty} \frac{-\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{x}}+1}{2} \\
  &\neq \lim_{x\to -\infty} \frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{x}}+1}{2}
\end{align}

One way to avoid errors of this sort (other than constant vigilance
when manipulating square roots of expressions over negative-valued variables)
is to begin by observing that
$$
\lim_{x\to -\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+2x} - x} 
 = \lim_{y\to +\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{y^2-2y} + y}.
$$
One can then work on the limit over $y,$ confident in the knowledge that
$\sqrt{y^2}/y = 1.$

Answer (score 2):

Let  $-1/x=h$

$x^2+2x=\dfrac{1-2h}{h^2}\implies\sqrt{x^2+2x}=\dfrac{\sqrt{1-2h}}{\sqrt{h^2}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{1-2h}}{|h|}$

As $h\to0^+, h>0,|h|=+h$

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\dfrac1{\sqrt{x^2+2x}-x}=\lim_{h\to0^+}\dfrac h{\sqrt{1-2h}+1}=?$$

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2056840/solving-lim-x-to-infty-sqrtx2x1-sqrt1-xx2-using-o-littl  OR http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1766582/evaluate-the-lim-x-to-infty-x-sqrtx2-2x/1766586#1766586