# Calculating limit in the infinity

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

Consider we want to find $\lim_{x \to -\infty} x(x+\sqrt{x^2 - 8})$ . I know the answer is this:[image: Answer]
But in the last step $\sqrt{x^2-8}$ has been changed to $\sqrt{x^2}$. I know we are dealing with infinity and $\infty - 8$ is also infinity but I'm looking for a proof which shows that change doesn't affect on the value of limit .

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2214526/find-lim-x-to-infty-sqrtx29x3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *But in the last step $\sqrt{x^2-8}$ has been changed to $\sqrt{x^2}$. I know we are dealing with infinity and $\infty - 8$ is also infinity but I'm looking for a proof which shows that change doesn't affect on the value of limit.*

One may write, as $x \to -\infty$,
$$
\sqrt{x^2-8}=\sqrt{x^2\left(1-\frac8{x^2}\right)}=\sqrt{x^2}\cdot \sqrt{1-\frac8{x^2}}
$$ and one may observe that
$$
\sqrt{1-\frac8{x^2}} \to \sqrt{1}=1\quad \text{as} \quad x \to -\infty.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Useful inequalities
for square roots are
$\sqrt{1+x}
\le 1+x/2
$
for $x \ge 0$
and
$\sqrt{1-x}
\le 1-x/2
$
for $0 \le x \le 1$.

To prove these,
just square both sides.

To go the other way,
we need bounds on $x$.

For example,
if
$\sqrt{1+x}
\ge 1+cx$
(where $c < \frac12$
because of the result above),
then,
squaring,
$1+x
\ge 1+2cx+c^2x^2
$
or
$x
\ge 2cx+c^2x^2
$
or
$1-2c
\ge c^2x
$
or
$x 
\le
\frac{1-2c}{c^2}
$.

Similarly,
if you want
$\sqrt{1-x}
\ge 1-cx$
(where $c > \frac12$
because of the result above),
then,
squaring,
$1-x
\ge 1-2cx+c^2x^2
$
or
$-x
\ge -2cx+c^2x^2
$
or
$2c-1
\ge c^2x
$
or
$x 
\le
\frac{2c-1}{c^2}
$.